# Visual Basic need to code accumulator for 4 category of totals

Tags: vb.net, accumulator

I am having an issue getting my totals to accumulate each time new data is entered.  The exercise is for a car dealer where each salesperson has an ID number that is 4 characters.  The first character is either the number 1 or 2.  The number 1 indicates the person sells new cars and a 2 indicates used.  The middle two characters are the person initials.  The last character is either an F or P.  The F stands for Full-Time and the P for Part-Time.  The app should allow you to enter in the ID and total number of cars sold for as many sales people as needed.  It should calculate and display the total number of cars sold by each of the following 4 categories: Full-Time employees, Part-Time employees, New-Car employees and Used-Car employees.  I am still very new to visual basic and having trouble understanding how to go about everything.  I seem to always run into issues when having to code anything that accumulates or has a counter.  Any help or guidance in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer Off

Public Class frmMain

    Dim intTotalPart As Integer = 0
    Dim intTotalNew As Integer = 0
    Dim intTotalUsed As Integer = 0
    Dim intTotalFull As Integer = 0

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtId_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtId.Enter
        txtId.SelectAll()
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtNumSold_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtNumSold.Enter
        txtNumSold.SelectAll()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
        'declare variables
        Dim strId As String
        Dim intNumSold As Integer
        Dim intTotalFullTime As Integer
        Dim intTotalPartTime As Integer
        Dim intTotalNewCar As Integer
        Dim intTotalUsedCar As Integer

        'store input entered by user
        strId = txtId.Text

        'convert input to a number
        Integer.TryParse(txtNumSold.Text, intNumSold)

        'add NumSold to Total 
        intTotalFull = intTotalFull + intTotalFullTime
        intTotalPart = intTotalPart + intTotalPartTime
        intTotalNew = intTotalNew + intTotalNewCar
        intTotalUsed = intTotalUsed + intTotalUsedCar

        'check for length of 4 characters
        'check for starting with 1 or 2
        'check for ending in F or P
        'if not display message, invalid ID
        'otherwise calculate totals sold
        Dim blnValidLength As Boolean = strId.Length.Equals(4)
        Dim blnId As Boolean = strId.ToUpper Like "[12][A-Z][A-Z][FP]"

        If Not blnValidLength OrElse Not blnId Then
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid ID. Must be 4 characters long, begin with 1 or 2 and end in F or P")
            Return
        Else
            'calculate number cars sold
            If strId.StartsWith("1") Then
                intTotalNewCar = CInt(txtNumSold.Text)
            End If

            If strId.StartsWith("2") Then
                intTotalUsedCar = CInt(txtNumSold.Text)
            End If

            If strId.EndsWith("F") Then
                intTotalFullTime = CInt(txtNumSold.Text)
            End If

            If strId.EndsWith("P") Then
                intTotalPartTime = CInt(txtNumSold.Text)
            End If

            'display number of cars sold
            lblTotalFullTime.Text = intTotalFullTime.ToString
            lblTotalPartTime.Text = intTotalPartTime.ToString
            lblTotalNew.Text = intTotalNewCar.ToString
            lblTotalUsed.Text = intTotalUsedCar.ToString

        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: if you want to accumulate, they should be `intTotalPartTime += CInt(txtNumSold.Text)`  However, I would use `Integer.TryParse` with a Textbox since it could contain a numeral or "I like pie".  And outside of class assignments concocted by someone who probably never wrote a single byte of for-profit code, *never, ever* use an ID which compounds 2 pieces of data or embeds other data (F,P).  If ziggy goes from part time to full does he get a new ID?

Comment: Thanks I to it now.  I also forgot to make my accumulators static so I finally figured it out.